# Sync paging for multiple DevExpress DevxDataView Control paging

Tags: asp.net, controls, devexpress, paging

I have a multiple DevxDataView controls on my web form.

- aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
- xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
- yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
- zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
- bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb

Each of the letters above represent a DevxDataView Control on my web page. With same number of data item each. Only the first and the last DataView controls have the pager controls available.

The problem I am facing now is the paging.

What I want to achieve is get a synchronous paging on all the controls i.e. if I click on the next, all the controls move to the next page and respectively of all the other operations (last, first and back).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the approach suggested in the http://www.devexpress.com/issue=Q354371 DX Support Center ticket.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to shed some light on the strategy? I am rather new to ASP.NET.

All these custom callbacks etc. are going over my head.

Comment: Further, how are following steps from your reference linked together?

3) Handle the client-side ASPxClientDataView.EndCallback event of the "left" ASPxDataView control;
4) Perform a custom callback of the "right" ASPxDataView control;

Comment: You can always get assistance from the DX team http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Issues/CreateIssue.aspx?issuetype=question